# Access denied for creating user on LDAP

Tags: ldap, ruby-on-rails

I have a web application that needs to be able to create users on a LDAP. I have created a `cn=intranet,dc=example,dc=com` and I need it to be able to add users unside `ou=People,dc=example,dc=com`.

So I am trying to add users as `cn=intranet` using attributes like:

```
    dn = "uid=something,ou=People,dc=telecom-etude,dc=com"
    attrs = {
        cn: 'something',
        givenName: 'something',
        sn: 'something',
        uid: 'something',
        displayName: 'something',
        objectClass: ["inetOrgPerson", 'top', 'Person' ],
    }
    ldap = Devise::LDAP::Connection.admin # returns a Net::LDAP binding with `cn=intranet`
    ldap.add(dn: dn, attributes: attrs)
```

Whatever I do, I seem to be stuck with

```
(Net::LDAP) LDAP Creation ERROR : #<OpenStruct code=50, error_message="no write access to parent", matched_dn="", message="Insufficient Access Rights">
(phpmyldap) 0x32 (LDAP_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS)
```

I have TRIED (meaning, non optimal but should definitely work ?) the following :

*The first entry is used for backups, ignore it (unless it's really relevant ?)*

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange,sambaLMPassword,sambaNTPa
 ssword,sambaPwdLastSet by self write by anonymous auth by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by dn="cn=jarvisrepl,dc=example,dc=com" write
 by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
oclAccess: {2}to * by dn="intranet,dc=example,dc=com" write
olcAccess: {3}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" writ
 e by * read
oclAccess: {4}to * by dn="intranet,dc=example,dc=com" write
```

I tried using wildcards * for access of cn="intranet", with both oclAccess AFTER and BEFORE the default access ({3}) but even this doesn't work, and I don't understand why.

Otherwise, from what I read, the best working config that I want should be this one :

```
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
oclAccess: {2}to dn.base="ou=People,dc=example,dc=com" attributes=children by dn="intranet,dc=example,dc=com" write
oclAccess: {3}to dn.onelevel="ou=People,dc=example,dc=com" by dn="intranet,dc=example,dc=com" write
olcAccess: {4}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" writ
 e by * read
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to move the
`"to * by * write"`
rule all the way up to the `{0}` slot before it will allow your `cn=intranet` users the ability to update or create new users.

I believe it may be because the default ACL in slot {0} is:
"to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by * none"
which blocks access to the userPassword attribute in spite of the new rule later on in the configuration.

It seems that the order matters and what your other rules are both make a huge difference in the end result.

Comment: Is This a Comment or an Answer? i BElive the first one.

Comment: @djdomi
I agree that this should probably have ben a comment rather than an answer, however I must be blind as the "comment" button does not show up for me for the original question, so I opted to simply answer seeing as the post was so old and I wanted to get my response down. Clearly I can comment back to my own "answer" but I still do not see a comment option for the question itself.

Comment: then fix up your answer and get a upvote